# UNION select sql statement returns duplicate results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, union

My objective is to have one record with both HomeNumber & OfficeNumber and I'm keeping the PersonID to reference the customer table. I'm thinking I shouldn't even be using a UNION but maybe a select query from two nested sub queries.

The results returned look like this.

```
1A370535-9432-45B9-8F08-004F040EE196    ''          ''
1A370535-9432-45B9-8F08-004F040EE196    6127319561  ''
E8FA1667-416C-4639-ADDC-02143D651B4E    ''          6512096719
E8FA1667-416C-4639-ADDC-02143D651B4E    6515786963  ''
```

Here my query:

```
    SELECT PhoneNumbers.PersonID, PhoneNumbers.HomeNum, PhoneNumbers.OfficeNum
    FROM (
      SELECT PhoneHub.PersonID, ISNULL(PhoneHub.PhoneNbr, '') AS HomeNum, '' AS OfficeNum
      FROM 
        --PhoneType INNER JOIN 
        PhoneHub --ON PhoneType.ID = PhoneHub.TypeID 
      WHERE 
        (PhoneHub.FranID = @FranID) AND
        (PhoneHub.TypeID = '28321161-668e-4a56-90be-67a146fa1353') -- Home# ID
      UNION
      SELECT PhoneHub.PersonID, '' AS HomeNum, ISNULL(PhoneHub.PhoneNbr, '') AS OffNum
      FROM 
        --PhoneType AS PhoneType_2 INNER JOIN 
        PhoneHub --AS PhoneHub ON PhoneType_2.ID = PhoneHub.TypeID
      WHERE 
        (PhoneHub.FranID = @FranID) AND
        (PhoneHub.TypeID = '02a4125b-b968-4dc6-9734-7f75f45f7635') --Office# ID
     ) AS PhoneNumbers  
     ORDER BY PhoneNumbers.PersonID
```

Table Schema - PhoneHub

```
PK  ID          uniqueidentifier    
FK  FranID      uniqueidentifier      Franchise.ID
FK  PersonID    uniqueidentifier      Customer.ID   
FK  TypeID      uniqueidentifier      PhoneType.ID
PhoneNbr    nvarchar(20)    
PhoneExt    nvarchar(10)    
IsDefault   bit
```

Comment: Please show your table schema for PhoneHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a pivot requirement.

```
   SELECT PersonID,
          Max(case when TypeID = '28321161-668e-4a56-90be-67a146fa1353'
                   then PhoneNbr End) HomeNum,
          Max(case when TypeID = '02a4125b-b968-4dc6-9734-7f75f45f7635'
                   then PhoneNbr End) OfficeNum
    FROM
      PhoneHub
    WHERE 
      PhoneHub.FranID = @FranID
    GROUP BY PersonID
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfect. One more question, I'm trying to understand why you referenced this to a 'pivot requirement'?

Comment: PIVOT is the process of turning multiple rows of the same data into columns. Here you have (person,phonenumber) as a "data row", which is being turned into one-column-per-number. That's the pattern known as pivoting.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  a.PersonID,Coalesce(home.PhoneNbr, '') AS HomeNum,Coalesce(office.PhoneNbr, '') AS OffNum from
(
      SELECT PhoneHub.PersonID
      FROM 
        PhoneHub
      WHERE 
        (PhoneHub.FranID = @FranID) AND
        (PhoneHub.TypeID = '28321161-668e-4a56-90be-67a146fa1353')
      UNION
      SELECT PhoneHub.PersonID
      FROM 
        PhoneHub
      WHERE 
        (PhoneHub.FranID = @FranID) AND
        (PhoneHub.TypeID = '02a4125b-b968-4dc6-9734-7f75f45f7635')
) as a
left join    PhoneHub home on   (home.PersonID = a.PersonID)  and  (home.FranID = @FranID) AND (home.TypeID = '28321161-668e-4a56-90be-67a146fa1353')
left join    PhoneHub office on (office.PersonID = a.PersonID)  and (office.FranID = @FranID) AND (office.TypeID = '02a4125b-b968-4dc6-9734-7f75f45f7635')
order by a.PersonID
```